# Django Rest Framework, Swagger and CORS

Tags: python, django, cors, swagger

I'm working on a project in `Django 1.6` with integrated `Django Rest Framework ver. 3.2.5` and compatible [Django Rest Swagger](http://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/stable-0.3.x/) `ver. 0.3.6`. 
When developing on local machine or running project from docker container Swagger displays endpoint descriptions correctly, but when opening api description URL on a remote server I'm receiving:

```
Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate access-control-origin settings.
```

[image]

From questions with similar problem I've found out that this problem may be solved by installing [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/tree/1.1.0).

I've added `corsheaders` to `INSTALLED APPS`,  `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'` to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` into project settings but I'm still receiving the same message as before, how should I configure `corsheaders` to resolve this issue?

> Noteworthy: if I change protocol in swagger path to `https` I then see endpoints:
>   [image: replaced http with https]
>
> But descriptions aren't expandable and there's a specific type of error
>   for each endpoint in console:
>   [image]

Comment: Have you added `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`  or added your domain in the whitelist tuple?

Comment: @PeterSobhi yes

Comment: @PeterSobhi I've added additional information, maybe you'd be this will help you to understand the issue better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by enabling https (in my docker-compose file):

```
HTTPS=on
```

And by setting SSL in nginx configuration:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl $https;
```